# How to pass array index into a function in solidity

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I had an array made of structs and I want to map an address to an instance of that struct array inside of a function. When i passed the index of that array instance like so,:

```
    array - Hotel[] public hotelroomsarray;
    struct - struct Hotel{
                uint256 roomNo;
                string suiteLevel;      
            }   
            
        function bookroom(uint256 _index) public payable uptofee{
            payable(owner).transfer(msg.value);
            roomstatus = Status.Occupied;
            bookertoroom[msg.sender] = hotelroomsarray[_index];         
        }
```

It keeps giving me the error:
Typeerror: Type struct bookHotel.Hotel storage ref is not implicitly
convertible to exppected type struct bookHotel.Hotel.

Full code (if it helps)

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

    contract bookHotel{
            // Create 5 hotels
            // book one hotel
            // keep track of who booked which hotel
            // makes sure room status is available
            // leave hotelroom
            // remove left from mapping and array
            // refund money if not liked

            address payable owner;

            constructor(){
                owner = payable(msg.sender);
            }

            struct Hotel{
                uint256 roomNo;
                string suiteLevel;      
            }   


            enum Status{
                Vacant,
                Occupied
            }

            Status roomstatus;
            
            mapping(address => Hotel[]) bookertoroom;
            mapping(Status => mapping(address => Hotel[])) bookertoroomTostatusofroom;
        
            Hotel[] public hotelroomsarray;
            
            
        function newHotel(uint256 _roomNo, string memory _suitelevel) external {
            hotelroomsarray.push(Hotel(_roomNo,_suitelevel));       
        }

        modifier uptofee{
            uint256 fee = 20;
            require(ETHtoUSD(msg.value) >= fee, "Not enough money");
            _;
        }

        modifier onlyOwner{
            require(msg.sender == owner, "You are not the owner");
            _;
        }
        
        function ETHtoUSD(uint256 _eth) public pure returns(uint256){
            uint256 convertedeth = (_eth * 1716);
            return convertedeth;
        }

        
        function bookroom(uint256 _index) public payable uptofee{
            payable(owner).transfer(msg.value);
            roomstatus = Status.Occupied;
            bookertoroom[msg.sender] = hotelroomsarray[_index];
            bookertoroomTostatusofroom[roomstatus][msg.value] = hotelroomsarray[_index];        
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
hotelroomsarray[_index];
```

returned a Hotel struct, not a Hotel array, it also seems an address must be assign to a Hotel, so change

```
mapping(address => Hotel[]) bookertoroom;
mapping(Status => mapping(address => Hotel[])) bookertoroomTostatusofroom;
```

to

```
mapping(address => Hotel) bookertoroom;
mapping(Status => mapping(address => Hotel)) bookertoroomTostatusofroom;
```

Answer (score 1):

Also in your bookertoroomTostatusofroom you have used msg.value instaead of msg.sender ,

```
function bookroom(uint256 _index) public payable uptofee{
            payable(owner).transfer(msg.value);
            roomstatus = Status.Occupied;
            bookertoroom[msg.sender] = hotelroomsarray[_index];
            bookertoroomTostatusofroom[roomstatus][msg.sender] = 
               hotelroomsarray[_index];        
        }
```